# Fastest way to modify a structure

Tags: matlab, optimization, structure

I have two different implementations right now on how to modify a base workspace structure from inside a function.

For my structure declaration in the base workspace:

```
arg = struct('aa', struct('abc',30));
```

The first function that I tested uses the `evalin` command:

```
function modifyArg1(parameter, value)
    evalin('base', [parameter '=' value ';'])
end
```

And is called this way :

```
modifyArg1('arg.aa.abc', '60')
```

The second function has the structure `arg` as input and output:

```
function [arg] = modifyArg2(arg, parameter1, parameter2, value)
    arg.(parameter1).(parameter2) = value;
end
```

And is called this way :

```
[arg] = modifyArg2(arg, 'aa', 'abc', 60);
```

I tested both function to see which one is the fastest :

```
tic
for ii = 1 : 10000
    [arg] = modifyArg2(arg, 'aa', 'abc', 60);
end
toc
tic
for ii = 1 : 10000
    modifyArgIn1('arg.aa.abc', '60');
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.141994 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.677188 seconds.
```

Hence, the second function is almost 5 times faster. Is there another way to do that faster?

Comment: Really, this just about how `eval` is a slow way to do anything and best avoided. You could try calling [`setfield`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/setfield.html) directly but I doubt it'd make much difference. Also, I struggle to imagine the code in which assigning structure fields, even dynamically, is a significant bottleneck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on `modifyArg2` since this is fastest way in your example. The high time you are getting is not associated with execution of `arg.(parameter1).(parameter2) = value;` but with the fact that you execute function `modifyArg2`. If you want to do it faster, one way is to use `arg.(parameter1).(parameter2) = value;` inline in your loop. For example:

```
parameter1 = 'aa';
parameter2 = 'abc';
tic
for ii = 1 : 10000   
    arg.(parameter1).(parameter2) = 60;     
end
toc
```

This in my tests is almost 10 times faster then executing `modifyArg2` function. Even this will be much faster than executing `modifyArg2` (as I tested):

```
tic
for ii = 1 : 10000   
    parameter1 = 'aa';
    parameter2 = 'abc';
    arg.(parameter1).(parameter2) = 60;     
end
toc
```